# Could Turing machines + random "do something" Turing machines cannot?

Tags: computer-science, random, turing-machines

A machine `G` that outputted a bit randomly could decide any language (by guessing luckily). Formally, for all languages `L`, for all natural numbers `k`, if you give `G` `k` finite-length inputs, `G` has `1/2^k` probability of deciding the "`k`-sampling" of `L`.

Turing machines cannot decide some languages. Formally, for some languages `L`, for all Turing Machines `M`, for all natural numbers `k`, for some natural numbers `i`, if you give `M` `k` finite-length inputs, it has `0` probability of deciding the "`k`-sampling" of `L` (since, for sufficiently small `i`, `M` may not halt in `i` steps).

Therefore, a simple machine that outputted randomly, though unlikely, could outperform some of the lengthiest Turing machines.

This is a contrived example. However, `1/2^k` > `0`; Maybe random can do something that Turing machines cannot. Hence the motivation for this question:

Could Turing machines + random "do something" Turing machines cannot?

If so, what does that mean for the [Church-Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis) that everything that can be computed can be computed by a Turing machine?

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes some familiarity with complexity classes. You may be interested in the complexity class [RP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RP_(complexity)). What is known is that $\textbf{P}\subset \textbf{RP}\subset \textbf{NP} \subset \textbf{EXPTIME}$. What this means is that we can simulate a Turing machine that is allowed to flip random bits and answers in polynomial time with a nondeterministic Turing machine, which in turn can be simulated by a Turing machine that runs in exponential time. So the answer to your question is no - any Turing machine that can use randomness can be simulated by one that doesn't but potentially takes longer.

Comment: I’m still learning about complexity classes. Are you saying randomized recursively enumerable is equivalent to recursively enumerable? How does that follow from RP being a subset of NP? Is randomness always a subset of non-determinism?

Answer (score 1):

This sort of question depends on pinning down what "do something" means. For example, here are a pair of results, one negative and one positive.

On the level of individual problems, there's a straightforward negative answer:

> **Negative**: There is no specific decision problem which can be solved with randomness but can't be solved classically. More precisely, if $X$ is any set which is computable relative to any $Y\in\mathcal{Y}$ with $\mathcal{Y}$ a set of oracles with positive measure, then $X$ is computable.

However, we can also ask about "higher-order" tasks (**mass problems**), where there is not a *single* correct solution but rather many possible ways to achieve the desired goal. Here we do see some positive results:

> **Positive**: There is a structure $\mathfrak{S}$ such that we can't build a copy of $\mathfrak{S}$ computably but we can build a copy of $\mathfrak{S}$ computably relative to even a little randomness - more precisely, the set of oracles computing copies of $\mathfrak{S}$ is exactly the set of noncomputable sets (any nontrivial computational power lets us build $\mathfrak{S}$).

The negative result is an easy measure-theoretic exercise; the positive result (the Slaman-Wehner theorem) is significantly more difficult.

Comment: Are oracles deterministic black boxes? If so, why would would the negative result imply something about a non-deterministic black box: randomness?